# PHP IP proxy server

Tags: php, tcp, proxy

I have public IP address but I want hide it. Is it possible write php-script to redirect ALL ip-packeges to my PC? Script will be located on free hosting.

Or other solution? Exists proxy-servers for hidding IP clients, why does not exist proxy for hidden IP adderss servers?

P.S. Sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is used for creating web apps, and that means, you can do things with the HTTP and HTTPS protocols.

Redirecting all IP packets would mean having to deal with any kind of IP protocol. Not possible.

Comment: Or other solution? Exists proxy-servers for hidding IP clients, why does not exist proxy for hidden IP adderss servers?